# After upgrading vCenter 5.0 to 5.0 U1, Server and Client are still reporting old version

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I downloaded VMware-VIMSetup-all-5.0.0-639890.iso and mounted it to my vCenter server. I then proceeded to upgrade the Server, Client, and Web Client components. However, even after a successful install and reboot the reported build numbers in Help > About vSphere have not changed. They are still being reported as the previous version: 623373.

The installer(s) recognized that an upgrade was going to be performed. I tried running the installer(s) again and they are asking to modify or remove the installations. Clearly the upgrade installer(s) has done what it was meant to do.

How is it that the product has not actually been upgraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vCenter 5.0.original is build 455964. You *are* running the correct U1 build. The build of the wrapper install package is often (always?) a higher number that the actual products inside.

Comment: I just got off the phone with VMware and this is correct. Though I think the documentation is a bit misleading in this regard. For example, at the very top of the page it states vCenter Server is 639890. http://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere5/doc/vsp_vc50_u1_rel_notes.html